# Error: database the transaction log for database is full due to 'checkpoint'

Tags: sql-server

We have an issue where one of our team didn't do backup to our database because he told us that when he tried to backup he received the error "database the transaction log for database is full due to 'checkpoint'", so what he did was **Detach**. Now, I'm try to attach the database again but I received also the error **atabase the transaction log for database is full due to 'checkpoint'** using UI and SQL Query.

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [CXSCSNSVR] ON 
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.CSSVR\MSSQL\DATA\backup\CXSCSNSVR_Data.MDF' ),
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.CSSVR\MSSQL\DATA\backup\CXSCSNSVR_Data_log.LDF' )
 FOR ATTACH
GO
```

Our drives have sufficient space 1TB to be exact.
I've tried also to changed the location of the LOG file but still the same error.

Comment: Try changing the `MAXSIZE` setting of the log file as part of the attach; it may be what's limiting the rebuild. (Disclaimer: I don't know if you can actually specify this while attaching.)

Comment: One of the links in this question may be helpful to you, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101585/transaction-log-is-full-due-to-checkpoint-for-db-in-simple-recovery-model

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on and is it full or simple recovery?

Comment: @DrHouseofSQL thanks for that info, we will try to update to SP2. We are using Windows Server 2012 Express and I think it is full recovery.